# Simple logarithm question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I understand that $\log{b}-\log{c} = \log {(\frac{b}{c})}$

However, why does $a\log{b}-a\log{c} = \log{(\frac{b}{c})}$

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: there is an $a$ missing on the rhs. So you are correct to be confused as there is a typo.

Comment: it isnot true, for example let $a=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$a\log b - a\log c = a\left(\log (b) - \log (c)\right)= a\log\left(\frac bc\right) = \log\left(\left(\frac bc\right)^a\right)$$